# PostgreSQL - Are case-sensitive names of tables nad columns feasible?

Tags: postgresql, case-sensitive

I did a bit of research about table and column names in **PostgreSQL**, which is totally new to me. All DBs I've worked before with were case-sensitive and I cannot imagine not using case sensitive names (due to clarity).

Now it's clear to me, that in PostgreSQL, creating table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Statuses (
    ID         SERIAL        NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    StatusText VARCHAR (30) 
);
```

Will result in table "statuses" with columns "id" and "statustext". To achieve desired result, we'd need to modify query to:

```
CREATE TABLE "Statuses" (
    "ID"         SERIAL        NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "StatusText" VARCHAR (30) 
);
```

Now the names will be "Statuses", "ID" and "StatusText". But what's absolutely odd to me, if we try to:

```
SELECT ID, StatusText FROM public.Statuses;
```

it won't work. One would expect, that "ID" would be interpreted as "id" both on storage side and query side (due to PSQL default lower case style), but it is NOT. Neither will work:

```
SELECT id, statustext FROM public.statuses;
```

To make it work, we need to do it like this:

```
SELECT "ID", "StatusText" FROM public."Statuses";
```

Now, unless I'm missing some important points or settings of PostgreSQL, all this seems to me totally **unfeasible**, a show-stopper in fact. Or do I miss a feasible way to work with PostgreSQL with case-sensitive entity names?

Comment: You should **really** avoid quoted identifiers (not only in Postgres but also in other DBMS like Oracle)

Comment: "*All DBs I've worked before with were case-sensitive*" - then you have only worked with database products that completely ignore the SQL standard. But you probably meant "case-preserving" rather than "case-sensitive" anyway (which is e.g. what Mircosoft SQL Server is doing - which is the only DBMS **I** know that does that). The SQL standard is pretty clear: only **quoted** identifiers are case **sensitive**. `StatusText`, `statustext`, `STATUSTEXT` or `StatusTEXT` are all **exactly** the same name in standard SQL. `"StatusText"` and `"StatusTEXT"` are **not** the same in SQL.

Comment: @a_horse: Yep, you're probably right about standards, I know. But standards do bear a historical burden and today's productivity is and practice is the other side of equation. Also, I absolutely understand the point of the standards about case sensitivity, but I don't understand the mixed approach of PostgreSQL. Or why they don't (?) have a flag to allow user to choose... I think everyone would sacrifice not being able to use same name in different cases twice for acutally being able to use mixed cases at all.

Comment: Postgres follows the SQL standard regarding case sensitivity. Just like Oracle, DB2, Firebird and many other DBMS systems. The only thing where they _deviate_ from the required behavior is that the names are folded to lowercase rather than uppercase as required by the standard (and as Oracle, DB2, Firebird and many other DBMS do).

Comment: @a_horse: SQL standards point-of-view is OK, but it's off-topic. I'm not asking why PSQL works that way, nor critisizing it generally. Yes, I think that the case-sensitivity is not handled well (unlike MSSQL, MySQL, SQLite I've been using), but it's not the point. What I really ask about is ***IF/HOW one can feasibly use case sensitive names***. So perhaps people do use PSQL with mixed cases and have their ways to handle that with PSQL *as is*.

Comment: If that is "unfeasible" for you, then you shouldn't use relational databases and SQL, because that's how it works. You're saying "if I do this, it hurts", and we tell you "then don't do it".

Comment: Again: my recommendation is: stay away from quoted identifiers (mixed case) in Postgres or any other DBMS product. And MySQL is not a good example to measure against. It reall sucks when it comes to "case-sensitivity" as it depends on so many different configuration parameters. It might even depend on the filesystem you are using....

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: No, it doesn't. There are decades of a *good* practice with mixed case names and it makes sense, as well as the standards make sense to PSQL. I'm not saying to anyone to avoid PostgreSQL because it works this way. I'm trying to find out, if it can work in real life (with mixed cases) and apart this off-topic discussion, I find more and more comments about PSQL being very troublesome in this area. If PSQL is not fitting my needs, then it's OK, I just want to be sure I get a good insight.